# cant put two file uploads in one form

Tags: forms, file-upload, file-handling

i'm trying to make a page where from you could update/upload a profile image or banner for your public profile from one form, but only the profile image works. and when i take out the profile image input, the banner works fine...
here's the most important part of my code:

```
    <form class="settings-form" action="(action)" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="img"/>
      <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="banner"/>
    </form>
```

does anybody have a solution for my issue?

Comment: Without knowing your server it's hard to know how you should approach this.
I would also change the id of the input fields so they are unique

Comment: what info would you need to solve my issue?

Comment: Any more information would be useful. I guess your writing php code cause that's another tag your active in here is the info from the official guide - http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php read it from start to bottom including the Warning and the comments. if you can't get it to work after that edit your question to add info on what you tried and which errors did you get